# The most simple way to implement a class factory?

Tags: rust

I have an interface:

```
trait Base {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32;
}
```

and its implementation for two different structs:

```
struct Derive1 {
    field1 : u8,
}

struct Derive2 {
    field2 : u16,
}

impl Base for Derive1 {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        println!("Derive1: {}", self.field1);
        self.field1 as i32
    }
}

impl Base for Derive2 {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        println!("Derive2: {}", self.field2);
        self.field2 as i32
    }
}
```

at runtime, depending on external conditions, I want create
`Derive1` or `Derive2` and then use `trait` corresponding to `struct`,
what should I use to hold `struct`?

To make it clear, for example I have:

```
struct Main<'a> {
    methods: &'a Base
}

impl <'a> Main <'a> {
    /*
    fn new(external_condition: bool) -> Main<'a> {

    }*/
    fn call(&self) {
        self.methods.foo();
    }
}
```

How can I implement `Main::new`, and how I should hold `Derive1` or `Derive2` in `Main`? Should I use `enum` or `Box`?

In the future, I may have `Derive3` and `Derive4`, so it would be good
to reduce number of places where `DeriveX` is mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Box`. `Box` allows you to store a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html) making all methods call dynamic dispatched. Using a `enum` would require adding a new variant for each `DeriveX` and a `match` for each method implementation.

Here is an example ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2876e20af898c6cdac564681e6d9a8a4&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn main() {
    // 1, 2, .. is decided in runtime
    let main = Main::new(1);
    main.call();
    let main = Main::new(2);
    main.call();
}

struct Main {
    methods: Box<Base>,
}

impl Main {
    fn new(num: usize) -> Main {
        let methods: Box<Base> = match num {
            1 => Box::new(Derive1 { field1: 1 }),
            2 => Box::new(Derive2 { field2: 2 }),
            _ => panic!(),
        };
        Main { methods: methods }
    }

    fn call(&self) {
        self.methods.foo();
    }
}

trait Base {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32;
}

struct Derive1 {
    field1: u8,
}

struct Derive2 {
    field2: u16,
}

impl Base for Derive1 {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        println!("Derive1: {}", self.field1);
        self.field1 as i32
    }
}

impl Base for Derive2 {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        println!("Derive2: {}", self.field2);
        self.field2 as i32
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Derive1: 1
Derive2: 2
```